# R: Multiple Operations on a vector

Tags: r, math, vector, rbind

I have a simple integer vector

```
 a<- c(5, 11, 20)
```

I want to apply multiple operations on it, e.g.,

```
a1<- a+1
a2<- a+2
a3<- a-3
```

...
and then combine the new vectors element wise. In this example, it would be:

```
new_a<-c(rbind(a1,a2,a3))
```

Since my original vector is quite large (~10,000), and the operations I want to apply are quite a few (~20), I am wondering if there is a more compact way to do the same?

Comment: Something like `as.vector(t(outer(a, c(1,2,-3), "+")))`?

Comment: Thank you Pascal, it fits my needs perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `outer` function:

```
a <- c(5, 11, 20)
op <- c(1, 2, -3)

new_a
# [1]  6  7  2 12 13  8 21 22 17

as.vector(t(outer(a, op, "+")))
# [1]  6  7  2 12 13  8 21 22 17
```